# Custom font - special character not showing

Tags: css, fonts, special-characters, font-face

I am using a custom font which is missing the special character: "@", but although I add more fonts on the font-family of the element the missing character isn't being replaced. Shouldn't it be displayed?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mainFont';
    src: url('fonts/font1.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/font1.svg') format('svg'), url('fonts/font1.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/font1.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

&

```
.text {
    font-family:"mainFont", Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

html

```
<span class="text">email @</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying multiple font-families instructs the browser to look for alternatives if the *entire font* is missing. It won't work for single characters.

You'll have to add the character to your font, or use a different font when using the `@` character.

[Here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/468/foss-font-editing-or-creation-tools-for-windows) is a list of Open-Source Windows font editors that may help.

As a really crappy alternative, you could use jQuery to find all `@` characters when the document loads and wrap a span around them that has a different font family. But that's likely to cause flickering on the user's screen.

Comment: There are some cool tools for Mac OS, too, let me know if you're on that platform

Comment: Thanks, I'll just edit the font and add the character myself.

Answer (score 1):

> I add more fonts on the font-family of the element the missing character isn't being replaced. Shouldn't it be displayed

No, it won't. Using multiple font names is useful when the first or second font is not found, then browser looks as the third one.

It seems the `@` sign character doesn't exist in your `mainFont` character set.

Answer (score 0):

In contradiction to the above answers, this has changed in the intervening decade.  As specified on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family

> The font-family property specifies a list of fonts, from highest priority to lowest. Font selection does not stop at the first font in the list that is on the user's system. Rather, font selection is done one character at a time, so that if an available font does not have a glyph for a needed character, the latter fonts are tried. When a font is only available in some styles, variants, or sizes, those properties may also influence which font family is chosen.